# Can we write App Prerequisites using Javascript? get edition of SharePoint using javascript

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-hosted-app, prerequisites

I am creating **SharePoint hosted app.** I have to develope an app such that it should work in all edition of
SharePoint and its features will vary from edition to edition.
Now I have couple of questions

1. Can we write pre-requests for SharePoint app by using Javascript as we add it in AppManifest.xml?
2. Can we detect edition of the SharePoint used where the app will be install?

We can have edition of SharePoint by C# code

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj659075.aspx#SP15DetectSKU...

But I am working on SharePoint hosted app so can we have the same by some javascript code? 
Please provide some reference links if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Can we get the which SharePoint Edition is being used (SharePoint foundation, Server or Enterprise) byJavascript?

there is no direct api available to do it but i have an idea for you what you can do make a rest api call to sharepoint using /_api/web/features.

it will give you list of all available web level features. now you can use the comparision chart feature wise from below link

http://blog.blksthl.com/2013/01/14/sharepoint-2013-feature-comparison-chart-all-editions/

and about change app's pre-requesits, I need to search for that one.